# converting from php to ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

After reading a few docs about ruby and the ruby on rails framework, i understand that data has to flow in an mvc structure. i have tried to convert the php script below to ruby but i've not been succesful. the comments explain my failures.

## Here is the php

```
                <form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
                    <fieldset class="step">
                        <legend>Account</legend>
                        <p>
                            <label for="receiverName">Receiver's name</label>
                            <input id="receiverName" value="" name="receiverName" />
                        </p>
            <p>
                            <label for="senderName">Sender's Name</label>
                            <input id="senderName" value="" name="senderName" />
                        </p>
            <p>
                            <label for="phonenumber">Receiver's Phone Number</label>
                            <input id="phonenumber" value="" name="phonenumber" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <label for="amount">Amount To Send</label>
                            <input id="amount" value="" name="amount" />
                        </p>

        <p class="submit">
                            <button name="sendButton1" value="sendButton" id="sendButton" type="submit">SEND</button>
                        </p>
                    </fieldset>

                </form>

                <?php
        /*if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

        }*/

        if(!isset($_POST['receiverName'])) die();

        $data = array(
        "username"=>"", // PLEASE ADD YÓUR SMS SERVER USERNAME HERE WITHIN THE QOUTES
        "from"=> "{$_POST['senderName']}",
        "recipients"=> "{$_POST['phonenumber']}",
        "message"=> "Dear {$_POST['receiverName']}, You have received  {$_POST['amount']}  from {$_POST['senderName']}",
        "password"=>"", // PLEASE ADD YOUR SMS SERVER ACCOUNT PASSWORD HERE WITHIN THE QUOTES
        "type"=>"normal"
        );

        $url = "http://smsdual.info/bulksms-api.php";
        $data = http_build_query ($data);

        // Send the POST request with cURL
        $ch = curl_init($url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;

    ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

## here is the attempted ruby and ruby on rails

```
#i am not sure wether to use the form_for or form_tag for submission of the form

#i ommited the form fields though i believe they are supposed to be implemented in the views of the app

#end of form

if !isset # i'm equally not sure about this line and where it goes in the rails framework

data = arrray{:username => '', :from => '', #don't know how the rest of the part falls in }

#and for the curl part i read somewhere that i would have to user the curb gem to implement that part. Some one help me fill the gaps
```

help

Comment: @meda: I'm sure you know that account creation date has nothing to do with how long someone has been actually using the site. If something is against the guidelines, please politely point it out rather than reprimanding the person in a condescending manner.

Comment: nothing in my comment is impolite actually asking for code conversion without attempt is rude

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is one language, but the Ruby on Rails framework is another world for itself.

You might want to grab a good beginner book about Rails, since your question is not simply answered in a few sentences and a few lines of code. Also be aware that even the simplest Rails projects consist of quite a few files and a non-trivial directory structure already, you can't simply write a single .rb file then slap it on a web server like with PHP.

Regarding the `curl` part in your PHP code, there sure must be a Gem for Ruby that does what PHP's `curl`module functions offer – check rubygems.org.

Comment: Instead of traditional books, I'd suggest with the popular Rails Tutorial, which is online and free: http://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: @julian: lets say i figure out a way to produce a ruby version of that php script, would it help me solve the rails world?

Comment: @user2903934, no it won't. Rails has a different take on web programming than PHP has. While in PHP the web server is basically a black box for you that simply feeds your scripts with data and sends the output back to the client, in Rails you basically also have to program/control the web server part which brings some more knowledge requirements. And that's just one thing. If you want to write a Rails app, you can't circumvent learning the basics with a broad introduction, because there's just so much to know and learn which you can't guess from previous PHP development knowledge alone.